# Databricks Community Edition Cluster won't start: Error: Waiting for cluster to start: Self-bootstrap timed out during launch

Tags: databricks

When I attempt to start a cluster on Databricks Community Edition I keep on getting the following error:

Waiting for cluster to start: Self-bootstrap timed out during launch

Please try again later and contact Databricks if the problem persists. databricks_error_message: Node daemon ping timeout in 780000 ms for instance i-0780bfa...

Can someone let me know if they have also been experiencing this problem lately?

Comment: So, I'm having major clusters even getting a cluster to spin up my Databricks Community Edition. Getting the following error: ```Exception when creating execution context: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timeout``` Any help much appreciated

Comment: Could have been an outage, next time you can check the status here https://status.databricks.com/ (under AWS)